# getting "strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues()" in Civi

Tags: civicrm

After I created an event, when I access the home page of the civi crm , I get the following errors:

> strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues()
>   should not be called statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 587. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateShortcutValues() should not be called
>   statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 287. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 587. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 587. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateDashboardValues() should not be called
>   statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 291. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 587. strict warning: Non-static method
>   CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues() should not be called statically in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Block.php on
>   line 587.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in recent versions. I suggest you upgrade to 4.3.8 or 4.4.4 (as of this post).
[CRM_Core_Block.php on github shows code updated to static method](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blame/master/CRM/Core/Block.php#L286)